# Extract only the values of array and print to blade LARAVEL

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to extract only the value of it the array and print to the blade. How can i achieve it? the picture below is the array.

[image]

```
public function view_send_email()
{
     $data["_email_list"]=Tbl_press_release_email::get();
     $data["sent_email"] = Request::input('sent_email');
     $mail = Session::get('email'); <--- array i want to get the value of it.
     dd($mail);
     return view("member.email_system.send_email_press_release",compact('data', 'mail'));

}
```

Comment: Happy to help I will send you the code in your gmail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view you can loop over the array like this :

```
@foreach($mail as $email)
    {{$email}}
@endforeach
```

To store them in the input you can do it like this :

```
{{ Form::text('emalis', implode(" ", $mail)) }}
```

Or

```
<input name="first_name" type="text" value={{implode(" ", $mail)}}>
```

Comment: can i store it in one `input` box? all of the emails?

Comment: yup can store in using @foreach($mail as $email)
    <input type="text" name="email" value="{{$email}}"/>
@endforeach

Comment: but the `input` is doubled. I want to store it all the emails in just one input box

Comment: Happy to help :)